# intercept-url pattern matching

Tags: spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 2.0.4 and I want to remove authentication for url like 
http://localhost:8080/myapp/images-by-url?url=http://www.example.com/1023

I add the following  in security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true" lowercase-comparisons="false">
    <intercept-url pattern="/images-by-url*" filters="none"/>
</http>
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I try

```
<intercept-url pattern="/images-by-url**" filters="none"/>
```

and it does not work either. Any idea?

Comment: If you have several requests to load the page at /images-by-url you must unsecure all of them. Can you tell us what exactly happens ? You get redirect or you get access denied or something else ?

Comment: Also posting all of your security config would help

Comment: If you have multiple intercept-url elements then remember they are considered in order. So if you have something like <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/> above the filters="none" entry that will take precedence.To help troubleshoot you might enable debug logging to see what is going on behind the scenes. If the logs do not help you you can post them here and it may help others figure out your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I enabled debugging and found out that it got stuck at /WEB/pages/images-by-url.jsp. 

So <intercept-url pattern="/**/images-by-url*" filters="none"/> works for me.